# How can I always get desktop version of web sites using Firefox for Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android

Some sites offer restricted functionality based on mobile user agent.  Although the current Firefox for Android (67.2.0) offers the ability to select `Desktop site` from the menu, I'm required to do that every time I open a new tab.

In the past, I thought there was a way to always go to a desktop version of a specific site, but I can't find it now.  Is there some `about:config` setting that can help?

Comment: try user agent apps from google play

Answer (score 1):

about:config is disabled in Firefox for Android, but if you switch to the Firefox Android Nightly version, about:config is currently working.

If a new key is added `general.useragent.override` and a desktop user agent string is used (for instance `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0`), then all web sites will receive that as your user agent.

This may not be desirable, since many web sites are difficult to navigate on the smaller mobile screen, but until there are user agent switcher add-ons that are allowed by the powers at GoogZilla, this is the best you can do.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem available any more.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I downloaded the latest "Firefox Android NIGHTLY", typed "about:config" in the address bar, typed "general.useragent.override" and my setting is still there, so I'm not sure what you saw that prompted your suggestion of not being available any more.

Comment: I only have Firefox Nightly available, no NIGHTLY. In this one, there is no general.useragent.override. The only similar one is general.useragent.compatMode.firefox

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава You need to ADD the entry.  It isn't there to be configured, but if you add it, it will take effect.

Comment: I see, thanks, it is working now.